# Using DISTINCT on a subquery to remove duplicates in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have question about use of Distinct with Entity Framework, using Sql 2005.  In this example:

```
practitioners = from p in context.Practitioners
                join pn in context.ProviderNetworks on
                     p.ProviderId equals pn.ProviderId
                (notNetworkIds.Contains(pn.Network))
                select p;

practitioners = practitioners
                  .Distinct()
                  .OrderByDescending(p => p.UpdateDate); 

data = practitioners.Skip(PageSize * (pageOffset ?? 0)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

It all works fine, but the use of `distinct` is very inefficient.  Larger result sets incur unacceptable performance.  The `DISTINCT` is killing me. The distinct is only needed because multiple networks can be queried, causing Providers records to be duplicated.  In effect I need to ask the DB "only return providers ONCE even if they're in multiple networks".  If I could place the `DISTINCT` on the ProviderNetworks, the query runs much faster.

How can I cause EF to add the `DISTINCT` only the subquery, not to the entire resultset?

The resulting simplified sql I DON'T want is:

```
select DISTINCT p.* from Providers 
inner join Networks pn on p.ProviderId = pn.ProviderId
where NetworkName in ('abc','def')
```

IDEAL sql is:

```
select p.* from Providers 
inner join (select DISTINCT ProviderId from Networks 
            where NetworkName in ('abc','def')) 
as pn on p.ProviderId = pn.ProviderId
```

Thanks
Dave

Comment: No, I think the ideal SQL should be `select * from Providers where ProviderId in (select ProviderId from Networks where NetworkName in ('abc','def'))` — the answer you received generates this SQL or something equivalent to it. Note that whether the subquery here has a `DISTINCT` on it or not makes no difference (at least not in MSSQL), they execute the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It does matter, however. When asking for more than one network, the provider results duplicate, due to the one-to-many relationship. Further, doing a distinct on just ONE field (provider Id) is more efficient than a distinct on all the rows of the provider table.

Comment: What @Timwi means is that if the sub-query is in a `IN` or `EXISTS` statement having `DISTINCT` does not matter as duplicates are already ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think you need a `Distinct` here but a `Exists` (or `Any` as it is called in Linq)

Try this:

```
    var q = (from p in context.Practitioners
            where context.ProviderNetworks.Any(pn => pn.ProviderId == p.ProviderId && notNetworkIds.Contains(pn.Network))
            orderby p.UpdateDate descending
            select p).Skip(PageSize * (pageOffset ?? 0)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
```